# How to turn an API response into a variable (Robot Framework)

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

I'm a beginner at Robot Framework and I have been trying to store one of the information provided by the API into a variable.
I made a Post request of this data:

```
${response}    POST On Session    studentsAPI    studentsDetails
...    data={"first_name": "Student Name1", "middle_name": "Name2", "last_name": "Name3","date_of_birth": "01/01/1995"}
...    headers=${HEADERS}
```

The data was posted on the API, and the log response ( **Log ${response.content}** ) was:

```
{"id":3746677,"first_name":"Student Name1","middle_name":"Name2","last_name":"Name3","date_of_birth":"09/12/1995"}
```

How can I get the "id" number that was generated, and put it into a variable to be used in the next tests?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, extract the required value into a variable

```
${Id}=  Get Value From Json  ${response.json()}  id
```

Then to use it within the whole test suite, use the keyword Set Suite Variable; e.g.,

```
Set Suite Variable  ${Id}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variable within the test suite. Use keyword [Set Suite Variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) alternatively you can also use Set Global Variable.
Your code can look something like this:

```
${response_json}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${response.content}""")    json
Set Suite Variable    ${ID}    ${response_json[id]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got this fail message: " Resolving variable '${response.content[id]}' failed: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not builtin_function_or_method "

Comment: I see, try using json.loads on the content first, i modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. get the id from Json response
2. get first element from the list

Your code can look something like this:

```
${Id}=  Get Value From Json  ${response.json()}  id

${IdFromList}=  Get From List   ${Id}  0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).